# Three.js GLTFLoader Request constructor: data:application/octet-stream;base64

Tags: three.js, gltf

There is a model that I export from **Cinema 4D R21.207 (RC)** via the **gLFT exporter** plugin, then I upload it to Three.js via **[GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader)** and I get an error

```
Request constructor: data:application/octet-stream;
```

Full code:

```js
// Request constructor: data:application/octet-stream;base64,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
```

---

I rechecked the model several times, couldn't find anything on the Internet.
Could you tell me where to dig at least?

---

P.s.

> Could it be that this is due to the weight of the model? I had previously made models with an average of 500k vertexes, their GLTF weighed up to 30-40 mb, the problematic model has 700k vertexes and 1kk polygons, and the weight of the GLTF is as much as 130 MB. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Does it work when you upload it to the Three.js editor? https://threejs.org/editor/

Comment: No, it doesn't work here and [there](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/). The problem is clearly with the model, but I don't know how to solve it..

Comment: Yeah, could be a number of things. Maybe your C4D exporter is outdated. Maybe you're exporting a GLTF+Binary duo, but only importing the `.bin`. Maybe you're using Draco compression, but not using the Draco loader. Hard to know exactly where in the process the problem is happening

Comment: @Marquizzo, Could it be that this is due to the weight of the model? I had previously made models with an average of 500k vertexes, their GLTF weighed up to 30-40 mb, the problematic model has 700k vertexes and 1kk polygons, and the weight of the GLTF is as much as 130 MB. Maybe that's the problem?